# Use existing Java classes from Jython REPL?

Tags: java, classpath, jython, read-eval-print-loop

I have a massive, unfamiliar Java codebase that I need to use in one of my projects, and unfortunately it's one of those situations where almost nothing is documented, and the very few things that are documented are of the "`setFoo(Foo foo) - sets the foo.`" variety. So the documentation generated with `javadoc` is not as helpful as it could be.

I'm more of a Lisp and Python guy myself, so my first thought was that I could learn a lot by interactively playing with some of the relevant classes. Enter the Jython REPL. The problem is that I can't figure out how to set the...the whatever (classpath?) to use them. Assume that I have two directories containing the subdirectories containing the `.java` files: `~/project/foo/src/` and `~/project/bar/src/`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you first need to *[compile](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/compile-136656.html)* those Java classes (you've referenced `src` directories in your question).

Once you have classes compiled, you can reference them via the classpath.

e.g.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append(r'C:\temp\sample.jar') 
>>> from org.my.package import MyClass
```

More info in [this document](http://www.devx.com/java/Article/27571/1954)

Comment: You know, I'd seen [this](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Using+WEKA+from+Jython) page and thought, "Oh, well that doesn't apply since I have .java files, not JARs." ...I also have JARs, I just--I don't even know what I was thinking :P Thanks a lot, though: that solved it.